# Segmentation Fault in C(core dumped)--simple pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Here please refer to the comment in the code.Segmentation Fault(core dumped) is happening here in the line *p=h. But when I am separately running this line separately in another new c file it is completely fine

```
#include<stdio.h>
int *max(int *a,int *b)
{
    if(*a>*b)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        return b;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int h=1;
    int *p;
    int i=1,j=2,k=3;
    int *a,*b,*c,*d;

    c=max(&i,&j);
    d=&i;

    printf("\nOutput from the max function %d\n",*c);
    printf("\n%d\n",*d);

    *p=h;  // Line where segmentation fault is occurring

    printf("\n%d\n",*p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `p` is not initialized.

Comment: it should be one of `p = &h;` and `p = malloc(sizeof(int)); *p = h;`

Comment: You don't need to use pointers with `p` at all here. Just declare it as `int p;` and assign `p = h`.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer `p` is not initialized.  It doesn't point to any storage.

Here you are trying to de-reference p and store the value from `h`:

`*p = h;`

But `p` doesn't point to any valid storage to hold that value.

Comment: Moreover the line `c=max(&i,&j);` is wrong since `max` returns `int` and `c` is `int*`

Comment: no the max function returns `int*`

Comment: Hum, right, I misread it.